# Oracle Binary File (dump: bmf) python/sql?

Tags: python, oracle, dump, cx-oracle

I am about to receive an Oracle dump (I'm assuming the proprietary binary file), I don't have Oracle and wanted to know if there was a way for me to convert this file into a CSV for example so I that I can load in into my existing software?

Using something like python/sql_alchemy/cx_Oracle/sqlite/postgresl?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have Oracle it [looks like you're out of luck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40188):

> Forget about processing a dump file. The only thing that can process a dump file is Oracle. Or you can spend a year reverse engineering it then have to start over again when the format changes. If you want to convert Oracle data to SQL, you aren't going to be able to use a dump file unless you import into Oracle first.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Oracle SQL Developer like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRe4GCHdh0U), which has a nice wizard for this.